# WebSocket opcode 7 with wss://

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, websocket

I tried to launch a server in **wss://** last Tuesday, but it didn't work. Today I decided to look at the WebSocket code and I found why my WebSocket closed directly. This is error code I found:

```
1002 Unsupported usage of rsv bits without negotiated extension.
VALUE OF RSV1:Opcode: 7, fin: false, length: 69, hasPayload: true, masked: false
```

My program works with **ws://** but not with **wss://**. I can't understand why TLS is blocked.

I precise IPtables are stopped and my certificate is OK.

Do you have any idea?

Below is my code if you want to look:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var express = require('express');

var serverTLS = express.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/notification_mail/notification.mail.com.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/notification_mail/notification.mail.com.crt')
});

serverTLS.configure(function(){
    serverTLS.set('views',__dirname);
    serverTLS.set('view engine','ejs');
});

serverTLS.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('index',{layout: false });
});

serverTLS.listen("443");

var wss = new WebSocketServer({ httpServer: serverTLS, autoAcceptConnections: true });

wss.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log((new Date()) + " Connection accepted.");

    connection.on('close', function(connection) {
            console.log((new Date()) + " Disconnected");
    });
});

console.log("Server launch");
```

And my HTML file

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Serveur 2</h1>
<div id="tchat"></div>
<script>
   var url = "wss://notification.mail.com";
   var wsCtor = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket;
   this.socket = new wsCtor(url, 'connect');

   this.socket.onclose = function(){
      alert ("Connection lost");
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is confusing, since

- opcode 7 is indeed reserved (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2), but
- it also mentions RSV1 which is also reserved, but gives no observed value

Did you try Chrome or IE10?

You could also try running [AutobahnTestsuite](http://www.autobahn.ws/testsuite) against your node server.

The testsuite has a fuzzingclient mode that supports WSS. The testsuite includes extensive wire log reports which might help finding out what happens.

Disclosure: I am original author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Answer (score -1):

I launched wss:// (but on .NET) and I got 7 opcode, too. I used `ReadTimeout` (`ReceiveTimeout`) every 5 seconds for sending "ping" to client. In ws:// and wss:// all worked well, but in wss:// every 5 seconds I got "7 opcode".

I removed the timeout and it worked.